# Writing to external XML using DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am trying to write to my XML file but am unsure of the syntax! I am able to open the XML file though. Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("xml/latestContent.xml");
$latestpic = $doc->getElementsByTagName("latestpic");
?>
```

I have used a previous method, but this is using the SIMPLE XML, which I no longer want to use:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("xml/latestContent.xml");
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());
$latestpic = $sxe->addChild("latestpic");
$latestpic->addChild("item", "Latest Pic");  
$latestpic->addChild("content", $latestPic);

$latestvid = $sxe->addChild("latestvideo");
$latestvid->addChild("item", "Latest Video");
$latestvid->addChild("content", $videoData);

$latestfact = $sxe->addChild("latestfact");
$latestfact->addChild("item", "Latest Fact");
$latestfact->addChild("content", $factData);  
$sxe->asXML("xml/latestContent.xml"); 
?>
```

How can I make my DOM do the same thing as the SIMPLE method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inferring what your latestContent.xml file looks like based on what your SimpleXML code is doing. For your current code to make sense, the latestContent.xml likely looks like this **before it gets modified by the SimpleXML code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root />
```

The equivalent code you wrote in SimpleXML using DOMDocument would then look like this:

```
<?php
// Load XML
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("xml/latestContent.xml");

// Get root element
$rootElement = $doc->documentElement;

// Create latestpic element as a child of the root element
$latestPicElement = $rootElement->appendChild($doc->createElement("latestpic"));
$latestPicElement->appendChild($doc->createElement("item", "Latest Pic"));
$latestPicElement->appendChild($doc->createElement("content", $latestPic));

// Create latestvideo element as a child of the root element
$latestVidElement = $rootElement->appendChild($doc->createElement("latestvideo"));
$latestVidElement->appendChild($doc->createElement("item", "Latest Video"));
$latestVidElement->appendChild($doc->createElement("content", $videoData));

// Create latestfact element as a child of the root element
$latestFactElement = $rootElement->appendChild($doc->createElement("latestfact"));
$latestFactElement->appendChild($doc->createElement("item", "Latest Fact"));
$latestFactElement->appendChild($doc->createElement("content", $factData));

// Save back to XML file
$doc->save("xml/latestContent.xml");
?>
```

HTH